# Can I replicate all dlls in Global assembly cache from one system to the other?

Tags: .net, iis, c#-4.0, gac

I need to have the same exact dlls on GAC as of my team mates system, is there any way by which I can do this? Any way to import the GAC from one system to the other instead of adding them one by one?

We have the same system configuraion (64 bit, windows 7 )

Comment: If you have .net 4, then you can try to copy C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Comment: The GAC is a pure deployment detail.  It requires an installer.  The .NET Framework uses the GAC, it has an installer.  You'd consider deploying your assemblies on the user's machine in the GAC, you need an installer.  Never put anything in the GAC without an installer or a deployment plan.  If you do anyway then you'll ask a question at SO that will not have a happy answer.

Comment: @VictorLeontyev : I am able to copy C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly  but I am not sure this way it will work all right

Comment: @HansPassant Thnx, I think this looks the best way as of now